# pagination link is not working for me

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I'm on the first page I click on pagination link(2),link(3), link(4)  page pagination link not working.

---

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Pagination extends CI_Controller
    {
    public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();

    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->model("Countries_Model");
    $this->load->library("pagination");
    }   
    public function index() {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pagination";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Countries_Model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;    
    $config['prev_link'] =TRUE; 


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Countries_Model
    ->get_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("pagination", $data);
    }
    }   ?>
```

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: when I click on 2nd, 3rd or last page link page shows the object not found error url:http://localhost/CI/pagination/10 Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: add your pagination link generated and error

Comment: sorry i cant able to understand how can i add pagination link generated error

Comment: Do, $config["uri_segment"] = 3; to $config["uri_segment"] = 2;    and $config['base_url'] = base_url().'pagination/index';

Comment: Look at this, it has a detailed explanation on how to use CI with pagination http://www.phpecosystem.com/2014/01/codeigniter-crud-with-pagination.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line :

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pagination";
```

to

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url("pagination/index");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this method fetches the data from your database:

```
 $data["results"] = $this->Countries_Model
->get_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
```

well you need also to pass an offset (the $offset is the segment 4 in your case),

in your controller

```
 public function index($offset = 0) {
  .....
 $this->Countries_Model
->get_countries($config["per_page"], $page,$offset);
 }
```

in your model

```
  get_countries($per_page, $page,$offset){
 ......
  $this->db->get('yourtable',$per_page, $offset);
 }
```

Comment: if i made the above changes also,2nd,3rd.. link is not working